# Uploading a file to Azure using UploadFromFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-storage

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

In one of my form, I am downloading a PDF from Azure and it is displayed using rasteredge (a PDF Viewer), this allow me to add and save annotation on the PDF.

The file with annotation is then saved in a folder at the root of my application (RasterEdge_Cache).
I would like to upload the PDF back into Azure, using the UploadFromFile function.

This is the function that I am using:

```
public static void UploadFile(DTO.BlobUpload b)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SN_ZEUXYS"]);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();            
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(b.Container);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(b.FileName);
    // b.FilePath = "~/RasterEdge_Cache/193304798925/output/A-0002-00008-00205Anno.pdf"
    blockBlob.UploadFromFile(b.FilePath);
}
```

This is the error message that I get:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IIS
>   Express\~\RasterEdge_Cache\193304798925\output\A-0002-00008-00205Anno.pdf'.

I assume that the file path is not correct, what path should I use, or am I using UploadFromFile correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path is a relative path so you should specify where exactly it relates to. Consider using [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) method to find out its physical path to the root of the application on your server.

```
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
HttpServerUtility server = httpContext.Server;
b.FilePath = server.MapPath("~/RasterEdge_Cache/193304798925/X.pdf")
```

Comment: Hi, 
I still have an error message, but it looks like the file has been found with server.MapPath.
Now this is the error that I have.

An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

So the question is, am I using the correct function: UploadFromFile?
blockBlob.UploadFromFile(b.FilePath);

Or should I use another function, and what function should I use and how.

Comment: It seems like a configuration issue. Please add your Azure configuration to your question. (Consider hiding sensitive information.)

Comment: I don't think it is an Azure configuration problem, as I use this config to stream a file back into the same storage. this is the app key in my web config:<add key="SN_ZEUXYS" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=zeuxysstorage;AccountKey=XXXXX" />

Answer (score 0):

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. So the question is, am I using the correct function: UploadFromFile? blockBlob.UploadFromFile(b.FilePath);

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-e2e-troubleshooting#about-the-sample-scenario), the "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." occurs when a upload operation against a container fails because the container or the blob is not found.

So I suggest you could firstly check the "b.Container,b.FileName"'s value is existing or you could use CreateIfNotExists method.

More details, you could refer to below codes.Hope it gives you some tips.

```
 protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            //check the b.Container value is right and exists
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("foobar");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("TestFile.pdf");
            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpServerUtility server = httpContext.Server;
            string FilePath = server.MapPath("~/test/TestFile.pdf");
            //by using this code will create the container if not exists
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
            blockBlob.UploadFromFile(FilePath);
         }
```